# Irreducible factorisation of polynomial over quotient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F=\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/<x^2+1>$.

Factor $x^4+2$ into irreducibles in $F[x]$.

I know that $F$ is a field since $x^2+1$ is irreducible.
The usual way to find out that a polynomial is irreducible is that it has no roots. But how to do it if the element of F is now of the form $g(x)+<x^2+1>$ where $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ and the zero element of $F$ is $<x^2+1>$. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: you should write : factor $y^4+2$ into irreducibles in $F[y]$, it would be much more clear

Comment: and since $F$ is a finite field (it is the field with $9$ elements ! just write the multiplication table), you can factor $y^4+2$ by trying dividing it by all the degree 1 polynomials of $F[y]$, then all the degree 2.

Comment: ok I get that now. sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @user1952009, yeah that's what I mean. But how to do that? Because the coefficient of $F[x]$ is from $F$ which is a quotient field. I still don't get it.

Comment: K.K.McDonald, that's fine, mate! Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: I find that $x+1$ has order $8$ : it is a generator of the multiplicative group. $(x+1)^2 = 2x$, $(x+1)^3 = 2x+1$, $(x+1)^4 = 2$, $(x+1)^5 = 2x+2$, $(x+1)^6 = x$, $(x+1)^7 = x+2$, $(x+1)^8 =1$. (that's the multiplication table of $F$)

Comment: now you can see that $(2x)^4 + 2 = (x+1)^8 +2 = 1+2 = 0$ hence $2x$ is a root of the polynomial $P(y) = y^4+2$ of $F[y]$ (because $P(2x) = 0$)

Comment: Oh I see. Can you elaborate how to do that multiplication.

Comment: which multiplication ? in $F$ the addition is still modulo $3$ : $2+1 = 0$, $2x+x= 0$, etc. and $(x+1)^2 = x^2+2x+1 = 2x$ (because $x^2+1 = 0$)...

Comment: Oh, I understand now how to do the multiplication table. Thanks. So, if it has a root, means $F[y]$ is reducible. So, if $2x$ is a root, then one the irreducible factor is of the form $x^2-2x$?

Comment: if $P(y)$ has $2x$ as one of its roots, then $P(y) = (y-2x)Q(y)$ for some polynomial $Q \in F[y]$ as I wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we find that $F = \mathbb{Z}_3[x] / (x^2+1)$ (which is the field with $9$ elements) has a cyclic multiplicative group with $8$ elements, whose generator is $x+1$

(proof : $(x+1)^2 = 2x$, $(2x)^2 = 2$, $2^2 = 1$, hence $(x+1)^8 = 1$ but $(x+1)^4 \ne 1$)

hence in $F$ the equation $y^4 = 1$ **has $4$ solutions** for $y$ : $$(x+1)^2 = 2x, \qquad(x+1)^4 = 2, \qquad (x+1)^6 = x, \qquad (x+1)^8 = 1$$ and that's cool because it means that in $F[y]$, the polynomial $y^4+2$ has $4$ distinct roots, hence :

$$y^4+2 = (y-2x)(y-2)(y-x)(y-1) = (y+x)(y+1)(y+2x)(y+2)$$

Comment: WOW. Crystal clear now :D Now, I completely understand. Thank you so soo much ^___^